# Seperate frontend code from Maven, Tomcat, jax-rs, Jersey project

Tags: java, repository, jax-rs, project

I am about to create a backend for a web application with Java servlets for a REST Api only, which should base on

- Java 11
- Maven
- Tomcat 9 (externally to project)
- JAX-RS
- Jersey

Then I am using Eclipse and I have created a *dynamic web project* and converted it to a Maven project.

Some problems in the project / folder structure might be caused by this. Here is the structure:

[image]

When I let the server run and hit *localhost:8080/hello_world* I can see the *index.html* in the browser.

I actually have two question:

1. Having a real *WebContent* is wrong, isn't it? I should have a real *webapps* folder, but the *WebContent* folder should be virtual (from Eclipse), right?
2. **How can I separate the *index.html* and or at least all other frontend resources (HTML, CSS, JS (React.js etc. pp.)) to a separate folder for heaving one repository for the Java Web Servcice and another one for the frontend?** Is this impossible with this tech stack?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your web service URL is not complete and you have to check your web.xml url-pattern tag and the Path annotation you have defined for your services.

In order to have a better prospect of Restful web services in Eclipse IDE, I suggest you follow these HelloWorld examples ([simple hello world rest service](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/web-services/java-restful-web-services-tutorial-for-beginner-with-jersey-and-tomcat) and  [CRUD web services using jersey](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/web-services/java-crud-restful-web-services-examples-with-jersey-and-tomcat)) to widen your horizon about some configurations in web.xml in which you have to define your container to your application server and corresponding pom.xml for jersey dependencies.

it is ok to have the WebContent folder in Dynamic Web Applications and there is nothing wrong with your project / folder structure

Comment: I am now using Apache for delivering the static files and redirecting api requests to Tomcat. So I can have separate repositories once I'm done with the setup.